# Get path of running process, when path contains space

Tags: macos, cocoa, awk, terminal, ps

I'm running `NSTask` in an macOS cocoa app with console command to determine the path of a running process

However, i am running into problems in parsing the path, if it contains whitespace

```
ps -ax | grep FMCore
10880 ??         0:50.37 /Applications/Suitcase Fusion.app/Contents/Resources/FMCore -standalone
11420 ttys004    0:00.00 grep FMCore
```

if i want to use `awk`, it gets split on the path whitespace, which is not desired

```
ps -ax | grep FMCore | awk '{print $4}'
/Applications/Suitcase
grep
```

How to get the path only, which in this case is

```
/Applications/Suitcase Fusion.app/Contents/Resources/FMCore
```

Comment: Try `ps -e -o cmd | grep [F]MCore | awk '{print $1" "$2}'`. Well, `awk '{print $1" "$2}'` is not a sure part: how do you plan to define the end of the path? Try replacing the awk command with `sed 's/\(FMCore[^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/'`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you only want a part of the command column, all the line up to the `FMCore` and the next space.

You may directly get the cmd column using `ps -Ao command` (in Linux, it is `ps -e -o cmd`), then grab the lines containing `FMCore` with `grep [F]MCore`, and then removing all after `FMCore` and any 0+ non-whitespace chars following it with

```
ps -Ao command | grep [F]MCore | sed 's/\(FMCore[^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/'
```

The `[F]MCore` is used instead of `FMCore` to avoid listing the `grep` command details.

The `'s/\(FMCore[^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/'` `sed` command will match `FMCore` + any 0+ non-whitespaces chars after it placing the string into Group 1, and `.*` will just match the rest of the string, and the `\1` placeholder will put back the `FMCore` with whitespaces back into the result.

It is also possible to use `awk` after getting the cmd string to grab all fields up to the first one having `FMCore`:

```
ps -Ao command | awk '/FMCore/{s=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i !~ /FMCore/) {s=s $i" "} else {s=s $i; break}; print s}'
```

Comment: ps: cmd: keyword not found :/

Comment: Well, probably that is related to the `ps` version,  I have `procps-ng version 3.3.10`

Comment: i am using the latest macOS 10.15 and bound the version of ps used

Comment: @PeterLapisu  Please try replacing the abbreviated `cmd` with the full `command`. Also, it seems `-a` is required, not `-e` in BSD `ps`. Try `ps -ao cmd` or `ps -Ao command`, instead of `ps -e -o cmd`, or maybe `ps -Ao comm`.

Comment: will this still work if there might be more whitespaces?

Comment: @PeterLapisu As I mentioned in my comment to the question, we need to know what the path boundaries are. How can you describe the end of the path you need to extract?

Comment: @PeterLapisu If you need to get all up to the first field starting with `-`, you may use `ps -Ao command | awk '/FMCore/{s = ""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i !~ /^-/) {s=s $i" "} else {break}; print s}'`. If the field must be of type `-<ANY_WORD_CHARS>`, use `/^-[[:alnum:]_]+$/` in the `awk` command

Comment: @PeterLapisu, could you please do let me know if you have tried my solution too?

Comment: @PeterLapisu Glad it finally worked as you need. If you need more advice feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
sed '/FMCore/s/.*[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ \(.* \).*/\1/'  Input_file
```

With `awk`

```
awk '/FMCore/ && match($0,/\/.* /){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/ +$/,"",val);print val}' Input_file
```

Comment: this also prints the e -standalone at the end

Comment: @PeterLapisu, not sure but your shown sample is not having it? Could you please elaborate more on this one?

Comment: @PeterLapisu, btw my awk solution will remove space at last of output too.

Answer (score 0):

Allow awk to conditionally test for the presence of the last field ($NF) to see if it contains -standalone, and if true, then remove it, and print the remaining command string up to FMCore. Tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G103).

```
ps -Ao command | awk '/FMCore/ {if ($NF == "-standalone")$NF="";print}'
```